# jsp not getting reincluded

Tags: jquery, jsp

In my application i have a jsp ,on which i include 3 jsp files.out of those 3 jsps i have one jsp with buttons.with the button pressed i want to change the content accordion2.jsp.
what im doing is once any button is pressed,im giving a call to a servlet,which does the logic part.nw from this servlet shall i send request to accordion2.jsp or the jsp that includes all this jsps??following is the script that im using alongwith the excerpt of the html.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // select all the links with class="lnk", when one of them is clicked, get its "href" value
      // load the content from that URL and place it into the tag with id="content"
      $('input.button').click(function() {

        var url = $(this).attr('src');
        alert(url);
        var status= $(this).attr('value');
          alert(status);
          alert(url+"?name="+status);
        $('.accordion2').detach();
        $('.accordion2').load(url+"?name="+status);
        alert("after load");
        return false;
      });
    });
    </script>



    </head>

    <body class="bodybg" >
    <div class="wrapwidth">
        <!--put header here -->
        <%@include file="header.jsp" %>
        <div class="mainbpdy">
            <!--put vetinav here-->
            <%@include file="vetinav.jsp" %>

            <div class="sroolable">

            <%@include file="accordion2.jsp" %>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">footer</div>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: from this servlet shall i send request to accordion2.jsp or the jsp that includes all this jsps?? Have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the top level JSP generates the whole page, it should be called to generate page again.